# How to create a full text index with PHP attributes and Symfony 6?

Tags: php, symfony, orm, annotations, attributes

I need to create a search input inside my symfony 6.0 project.
I'm using PHP 8.1.5

In the old days i used the following syntax with annotations :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="category", indexes={@ORM\Index(columns={"name", "description"}, flags={"fulltext"})})
 */
class Category
{
```

But right now i'm not able to find the good way to do it using attributes.
I tried the following :

```
#[ORM\Index(name: 'category_idx', columns: ['name', 'description'])]
```

but the migration didn't create a full text index.

Could you please tell me how you did it if you already had this situation ?

Comment: Have you seen this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71411781/231316

Comment: Yes i have but it doesn't contain what i need (the fulltext flag).

Comment: Although the documentation doesn't list it, the [source code](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/2.12.x/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Index.php) for the `Index` attribute still lists a `flags` parameter, so you should be able to use it just the same.

Comment: This is the answer you were right. I can't upvote your comment but thank you very much.
In the end i did: 

`#[ORM\Index(name: 'category_idx', columns: ['name', 'description'], flags: ['fulltext'])]`

and it worked

Comment: That's great. Could you post that as an answer?

Comment: Well it's your answer tbh can't you post it ?

Comment: I might have pointed you in the right direction but you ultimately wrote the code, so I’m fine with you just posting an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who are looking for the same answer here it is.

```
#[ORM\Index(name: 'category_idx', columns: ['name', 'description'], flags: ['fulltext'])]
```

This will indeed create a TABLE with a fulltext index.

Comment: Seems Symfony changed annotations syntax in the 6th version. Where I can read more about this? 

Previously it was something like this:
@ORM\Table(name="product_option_groups",
      indexes={
           @ORM\Index(name="Vendor_GroupId", columns={"id", "vendor_id"})
     })